# Why doesn't the constructor log event?

Tags: solidity, remix

The contract b does not log any event in Remix console:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract a {
    event Log(string);
    constructor(string memory astr) {
        emit Log(astr);
    }
}

contract b is a {
    constructor(string memory bstr) a("aaaa") {
        emit Log(bstr);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you switch to contract B on remix interface before interacting with the contract?

Comment: The logs are generated. It seems a remix limitation/bug. I suggest to report the issue to remix developers here https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project.